# After subtitle video one of my audio track is missing

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video and a soft subtitle of the video.The video had 3 audio(track1 track2 track3) I use this command

ffmpeg -i /sdcard/input.mkv -vf subtitles=/sdcard/input.ass /sdcard/hrdcoded.mp4

In this command I not only hardcode subtitles but also convert the video to mp4. The process start properly but when it finished I saw I was have 3 audio track(track1 track2 track3) now it have audio track1. Other tracks are missing. What command should i use to have all audio track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg, by default, only picks one stream of each type (video, audio, subtitles). The user needs to set map option to select tracks for an output.

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/input.mkv -vf subtitles=/sdcard/input.ass -map 0 -c:a copy /sdcard/hrdcoded.mp4
```

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection